What is the name of the movie with a car that's throttle is stuck?
I think I saw this movie in the early 2000s. There were three people in car (1 woman and 2 men) that didn't know each other well. I think they just met each other. The woman was driving and a white man (in a suit, probably working in insurance or something) and a colored man who gets wounded throughout the movie. They are driving way too fast all the time because the throttle was stuck and they couldn't get the car to stop. That's about all I can remember.

Can you use a more descriptive term than "colored"? Black, Hispanic, Indian, Native... Something. I'm not sure what you mean by "colored".

Seems you're looking for Runaway Car (AKA Out of Control) from 1997. From Rotten Tomatoes:

Best described as an amalgam of Speed and Vanishing Point, the made-for-television action thriller Runaway Car stars fair-haired Nina Siemaszko as Jenny, a painfully inept and butterfingered young nurse who winds up at the wheel of a battered old car full of passengers - including a businessman in need of a ride (Judge Reinhold), a [black] skateboarder whom she almost hits, and her infant niece - only to discover that the accelerator is stuck. The only option, then, is to pilot the vehicle at absurdly high speeds until it runs completely out of gas.

Here's a 3-minute recap video of the film:




I really hate the "accelerator is stuck" trope.  How stupid are these people?  Throw the car into neutral.  Stand on the brake pedal.  Pull the damn handbrake.  Put the car nose into a tree or wall.  Do any or all of those before the speed gets too high.  Anything else is just stupid.  Ok... end of rant...
